# CSS drop-down menu bar, transparent with rounded corners

Tags: css, jquery, menu

Looking for a menu that resembles:

[image]

Having the following requirements:

- Transparent with rounded corners
- Floats at the top of the browser window
- Mostly hidden until the cursor approaches
- Cross-browser (except for IE6) and mobile support
- Uses `<ul>` and `<li>`
- Uses jQuery or CSS
- Width stretches dynamically, based on number of menu items
- Optionally, supports multiple levels

I have looked through some of the following:

http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/

But did not find examples that quite fit the desired look.

What web sites show how to implement a menu system with most of the given requirements?

Thank you!

### Related Links

Links that show how to implement various parts of this problem:

- http://www.quackit.com/css/codes/css_floating_menu.cfm
- http://www.css3.info/introduction-opacity-rgba/
- http://www.cssportal.com/css3-rounded-corner/
- http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/
- http://sperling.com/examples/menuh/
- http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FixedFadeOutMenu/
- http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FixedNavigationTutorial/
- http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/wp-content/uploads/file/jquery-sliding-menu/
- http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/386_navigation/top-nav-demo/index.html

Comment: You have listed resources which describe how to build a solution to your very specific requirements, however, the only question in your post is "Any ideas?" Please elaborate on what you expect in reply to your question/what it is you want to know.

Comment: This is both not a real question and also way, way too localized (ie. help me turn this exact design into code). Implementing a design in code is the job of a web developer, not a Q&A forum.

Comment: If you're having a problem with a specific part, please let us know, but stackoverflow isn't here to do your homework, or build your website.

Comment: At 7k rep, I think you;d know this isn't a job-listing website.

Comment: @djlumely The OP didn't ask us to build this menu for him, he said "What web sites show how to implement a menu system with most of the given requirements?". Please note this question was originally posted on webmasters.stackexchange.com. I think he was just asking the web master there if they had seen such a menu implemented somewhere. I think it's a valid question and appreciate the detail he has added. +1 from me.

Comment: I don't think this should have been migrated from webmasters. It is not a programming question and doesn't belong here (as the down votes show).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested it yet in all browsers, but here you have http://jsfiddle.net/A53Py/5/.

No css3 needed for this, but IE7+ rounded corners. You can use border images for it instead.